# Android Studio: TableView Issue

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, gradle

Can someone assist me in dealing with the following errors, [1] and [2], from the code below?
I'm a begineering using andriod studio IDE, any advice and recommendations are welcome!

[1] Class referenced in the layout file, `de.codecrafters.tableview.Table`, was not found in the project or the libraries
[2] Cannot resolve class de.codecrafters.tableview.Table

```
// code inside xml file 
       <de.codecrafters.tableview.Table            
           android:id="@+id/table_001"           
           android:layout_width="match_parent"     
           android:layout_height="match_parent"    
           android:layout_marginTop="65dp"         
           android:background="#4c4e4d"            
           app:tableView_columnCount="4">          
                                                   
       </de.codecrafters.tableview.Table>
```

I've added the following code into the build.grade.kts (Module :app) and selected "sync now" which is suppose to prevent the errors [1] and [2].

```
dependencies {
// more code ...

//https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/swiperefreshlayout#kts
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0") // used for data table

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecrafters.tableview/tableview
    implementation("de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0")
}
```

Edit:
looking into Tableview some more, I found out that tableview is not built in Andriod studio: https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The README you linked and the dependency you have added in your build.gradle are different dependencies? Can you please make your question more clear which dependency you are actually trying to use? Did you follow the setup instructions correctly?